# How to append two different tables to same pdf file which are generated through 2 different functions using reportlab

Tags: python, function, pdf, reportlab

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, inch
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle

def Pdf_report_Generation(Test_report_Name,Paragraph,data):
    global doc
    elements = []
    Column=[]

    #Test report name
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(Test_report_Name, pagesize=letter)

    #for determining no of rows and columns
    for sublist_index,sublist in enumerate(data):
        print "No of rows",len(sublist)
        Column.append(sublist_index)
        print "No of Columns",len(Column)
        t=Table(data,len(sublist)*[inch], len(Column)*[inch])

        #Forming a grid
        t.setStyle(TableStyle([('ALIGN',(0,0),(-1,-1),'CENTER'),
                        ('INNERGRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                            ('BOX', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black)
                        ]))
    for sublist_index,sublist in enumerate(data):
        if sublist_index==0:
            print "sublist",sublist
            t.setStyle(TableStyle([('BACKGROUND',(0,0),(-1,0),colors.aqua)
                        ]))

        for element_index,element in enumerate(sublist):
            if element == 'Pass':
                Index_with_pass= (element_index,sublist_index)
                print "Index_with_pass",Index_with_pass
                t.setStyle(TableStyle([('TEXTCOLOR',Index_with_pass,Index_with_pass,colors.green)]))

            if element == 'Fail':
                Index_With_Fail= (element_index,sublist_index)
                print "Index_With_Fail",Index_With_Fail
                t.setStyle(TableStyle([('TEXTCOLOR',Index_With_Fail,Index_With_Fail,colors.red)]))

    Para=Table(Paragraph)
    elements.append(Para)
    elements.append(t)
    print os.getcwd()
    return doc,elements
    #doc.build(elements)

def tc1():
    global paragraph,data_tc1
    paragraph=[["step1:hello"]]
    data_tc1= [['Test_Name', 'value','Software', 'Steps','Result'],
               ['In1'     , 11, 12,  'Step1','Pass'],
               ['In2'           , 13, 14,  'Step2','Pass'],
               ['In3'       , 15, 16,  'Step3','Fail'],
               ['In4'      , 17, 18,  'Step4','Fail']]
    return paragraph,data_tc1

def tc2():
    global data_tc2
    data_tc2= [['In5'             , 17, 18,  'Step5','Fail'],
               ['In6'              , 17, 18,  'Step6','Fail']]
    return data_tc2

def main():
    global paragraph,data_tc1
    global data_tc2,doc
    ##    print tc1()
    ##    print tc2()
    data=[]
    testcases=[tc1(),tc2()]
    print type(tc1())
    for testcase_index,test_case in enumerate(testcases):
        #print test_case
        data.append(test_case)
        print "elements",Pdf_report_Generation("Test_report_180975816.pdf",paragraph,data)
        doc.build(Pdf_report_Generation("Test_report_180975816.pdf",paragraph,data))
main()
```

I created a function which takes data as input and creates table in pdf. Now I have tc1 and tc2 functions which has two different sets of data. I want to call these two functions into main function and I want to create one pdf file which should contain both data_tc1 and data_tc2 tables.Will it be possible?I have tried above mentioned code and I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\table_Call.py", line 90, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\UsersDesktop\table_Call.py", line 89, in main
  doc.build(Pdf_report_Generation("Test_report_180975816.pdf",paragraph,data))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\doctemplate.py", line 1200, in build
    BaseDocTemplate.build(self,flowables, canvasmaker=canvasmaker)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\doctemplate.py", line 956, in build
self.handle_flowable(flowables)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\doctemplate.py", line 797, in handle_flowable
self.handle_keepWithNext(flowables)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\reportlab\platypus\doctemplate.py", line 764, in handle_keepWithNext
while i<n and flowables[i].getKeepWithNext(): i += 1
AttributeError: SimpleDocTemplate instance has no attribute 'getKeepWithNext'
```

Comment: Please,can anyone provide solution to this?